# how to correctly import modules in python on lambda project

Tags: python, lambda, package, python-import

I'm making a lambda function in python. 
Here is the current structure of my project.

```
lambda/
|-- datas/
|   |-- d.json
|
|-- package_name/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- lambda_function.py # this is using d.json
|   |-- a.py # this is some classes used on lambda_function
|   |-- b.py # this is some basic time functions that a.py need
|   |-- utils.py
|
|-- tests/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- test_main.py
|-- setup.py
|-- README
```

I have some issues with imports.

```
# lambda_function.py files
from a import *
from utils import *

# a.py files
from b import *

# b.py files
from a import *
```

It's working locally, but not in aws lambda console. To make it working in aws lambda console, I need to change this :

```
# lambda_function.py files
from package_name.a import *
```

So my first question is : why ?

And my second question is : If I want to import package_name/a.py in tests/tests_main.py, what should I do ?

I tried

```
from a import *
from package_name import *
```

But it doesn't work

I'm still a little bit lost with how imports work, even after reading what internet had to say about it.
Moreover, I'm not sure about my project files structure (but it's an other subject I guess)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
# lambda_function.py files
from .a import *
from .utils import *

# a.py files
from .b import *

# b.py files
from .a import *
```

this will tell that from the current directory read the module and import all 
functions, classess, variables.

Comment: That's working on aws lambda console. But locally, I get this error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.a'; '__main__' is not a package. What's the difference between aws lambda console and when I execute lambda_function.py locally on vscode ?

Comment: @MatthieuVeron you can use something like [python-lambda-local](https://pypi.org/project/python-lambda-local/) to test your function locally.

Comment: @MatthieuVeron is main your package name ?

Comment: @MatthieuVeron can you tell what is main , which you have wrote in code ?, better to add part where is error coming and what error it is

Comment: I don't have any file named "main". I don't really understand what do you want me to add.  Here is the error : from .a import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.a'; '__main__' is not a package. The error appeared when I ran the code on lambda_function.py

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding your current working directory path to the python libraries path

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
```